# microsoft access database - cloud options

Tags: ms-access

I have a microsoft access database that I use to track client specifications. I would like store the front-end and back-end database in the cloud and use it in real time. What recommendations and cheap options are available

Comment: a real cloud or are you simply trying to use the front-end from different (geo) locations?

Comment: my employees using the front end from different locations.(construction) i.e.. in the field or the office.

Comment: simply migrate is to full website or buy cheap MySQL hosting with dedicated IP. use ODBC to connect to the back-end server. Job done. No need to have expensive cloud

Comment: Close-voters could at least leave a comment.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to host the frontend and backend on an AWS t2.small instance running Windows:

[AWS instance](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/)

Then access this via Remote Desktop as any other machine.

Comment: does it allow concurrent usage?

Comment: Technically yes, it's a version 2008 R2, but you may need to add some CALs.

Comment: @Gustav - I've stated another question which I'm hoping you might have time to comment on. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32653858/how-to-migrate-a-access-database-to-be-available-by-multiple-users-from-anywhere).

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to use your Access database locally and update the data on the cloud, using Google Drive or other similar services to share this among several users, it is an asynchronous solution though.

Answer (score 0):

deployment of a multi user Access app, among geographically separated users, is via Remote Desktop Server, aka citrix, aka terminal services...

in any multi user deployment the app is split, and each user has their own front end file - and all connect to the one single back end file.  this remains true in an RDS deployment.

this is a main stream method to deploy, and very functional....lots of orgs do virtual desktop now, and then there are hosting companies that will do a single app... whether or not one views this as "cheap" however is in the eye of the beholder... but any other attempt/method is generally a kludge and is typically round-robin where only 1 user at a time can use the app... also - - one does not put the WAN in the middle... both the front and back end files are RDS and so the user simply has Win10 and does not need any Access or Office license on their local pc.